# JSON composite array declaration problem

Tags: javascript, json

I need something like this

```
var MyObj = { "pC" : [  { "title" : "Directory", "name" : "abcd1" , 
                          "values" : [ { "ss" : "abcd2" , "data" : "home" },
                                       { "ss": "abcd3" , "data" : "scorpio"} ]
                        }
                     ]};

  document.write(MyObj.pC[0].values[0].ss;
```

This does not work. Am I missing something silly ?

Comment: you have missed closing bracket in `document.write(MyObj.pC[0].values[0].ss);`

Comment: I assume you actually close the parentheses on the document.write call in your actual code?

Comment: you may find http://www.jslint.com/ helpful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a closing paren:

```
document.write(MyObj.pC[0].values[0].ss);
```

But it wasn't really silly. :-)

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `)` in `document.write(MyObj.pC[0].values[0].ss;`

Comment: great!! Thanks a lot to everyone. Is there any debugger to catch these kind of errors.

Comment: in Moziila, you have Console Error option in Tools, and addon like fire bug can be used for debugging.

Comment: Gaurav meant "Error Console". Besides Firebug, there's also an excellent javascript debugger for FF called "JavaScript Debugger" (code name "Venkman") which is great... when it isn't crashing. IE8/9, and Webkit browsers (e.g., Chrome, Safari) also have a built-in debugger/console.

Answer (score 1):

you have missed closing bracket in

```
document.write(MyObj.pC[0].values[0].ss);
```